# Lazy loading object causing issue during serialization. Getting 500 internal server error

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, lazy-loading

I have written API's which are resulting in 500 error when hit through postman or browser. However, when I debug and see server is not throwing any error and in fact returning a proper response. Other controller I have implemented in a similar way is returning expected result. below is my controller code. Has anyone faced similar situation. Kindly help.

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(value="/byPatientId/{patientId}", produces = "application/json")
    public List<ContactInfo> getAllContacts(@PathVariable String patientId) {
        logger.info("Received request for List of ContactInfo for patientId: "+patientId);
        List<ContactInfo> list = 
         contactInfoService.getAllContacts(patientId);
        return list;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/byContactId/{contactId}")
    public ContactInfo getContactById(@PathVariable Integer contactId) {
        logger.info("Received request for ContactInfo for contactId: "+contactId);
        return contactInfoService.getContactById(contactId);
    }
```

Comment: You may need to add logs with related code

Comment: What do the browser developer tools or Postman have in the body of the 500 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with one of the dependent object which was having oneToMany relationship with the return type object and it was set to **Lazy loading** and issue was during the serialization.

> Either we can change it to Eager loading or ignore the dependent object by adding `@JsonIgnore` on dependent object.

I handled it by adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation on top of the dependent object as I don't need the dependent object in this particular usecase. Issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Controller annotated? is it with @Controller or @Rest?

- @RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody(for serializing the response and pass it into the HttpResponse.

Add the @ResponseBody in your methods on the controller or change the @Controller tag into a @RestController(take into account that @RestController is available since 4.0 Spring version).

More info:https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

Comment: I have annotated with `@RestController` only. The problem was with one of the dependent object which was set to lazy loading. I handled it by adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Anyway thanks for the answer